# Tengo una duda con mi consulta ajax

Tags: php, ajax, script

Simplemente quiero que al ingresar un código, me busque en la base de datos si existe ese codigo y me tire un nombre nada mas. les paso el código para que vean un poco y me comenten si me falta algo, les agradecería mucho.

Mi formulario

```
<form id="formularioIndex" method="POST">

   <div id="mostarMensaje"></div> 
   <input type="text" name="idCliente" id="idCliente" placeholder="ID"  required />
   <button id="btnCliente">Buscar Cliente</button>

</form>
```

Y aquí esta mi script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('btnCliente').click(function(){
          var datos=$('formularioIndex').serialize();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "consultabd.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function(r){
              if(r==1){
                alert("Busqueda exitosa");

              }else{
                alert("Error en la busqueda");
              }
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
      });
</script>
```

Y por ultimo mi consulta en la base de php (consultadb.php)

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','prestamos');
    $idcliente = $_POST['idCliente'];
    $sql="SELECT nombreyapellido FROM cliente WHERE idcliente = $idcliente";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $salida= "";
    if($resultado->num_rows>0){
        
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            $salida = $fila['nombreyapellido'];
        }
    }else{
        $salida = "No hay datos";
    }
    echo $salida;

?>
```

ah como información extra mi base de datos solo tiene estos campos (id, nombreyapellido) nada mas

Comment: No funciona el codigo que hicistes? O te sale algun error

Comment: no amigo, y ya he revisado mucho, de hecho de un tutorial estaba siguiendo y no se que he hecho mal

Comment: Olvidaste los `#` para acceder a elementos por ID, por ejemplo: `$('#btnCliente')`

Comment: @triby si amigo e olvida eso y ahora ya ingresa en el script pero ahora mi problema es que no recibo respuesta de mi php

Comment: prueba `idcliente = ".$idcliente` en vez de `idcliente = $idcliente"`

Comment: Gente ya solucione, no se como le afectaba pero cargue un dato cualquiera en el div donde quiero que aparezca el resultado y ahí si me funciono. Muchas gracias a todos